# If condition in mail body phpmailer

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using Phpmailer and I am currently emailing the data from my database. However, I need to have a color coding depending on the chosen condition. For example, if the remarks is proceed, the data cell should be in green color and red if hold. Im not really sure how to apply if loop inside an echo. Please help

```html
while ($rowwaf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryres)){
$mailbody = "
 Good Day!<br><br>
 Please see details below<br><br>
 <strong>Details:</strong><br><br>
 <table class=\"table\" cellpadding=\"5\" rules=\"all\" frame=\"box\" border=\"1\">
   
   <tr><td class=\"data\"><strong>REQUEST DATE:</strong></td><td>".$rowwaf["req_date"]."</td></tr>
   <tr><td class=\"data\"><strong>ISSUE ENCOUNTERED:</strong></td><td>".$rowwaf["issue"]."</td></tr> 
   <tr><td class=\"data\"><strong>URGENCY:</strong> </td><td>".$rowwaf["urgency"]."</td></tr>
   <tr><td class=\"data\"><strong>REQUESTOR:</strong></td><td>".$rowwaf["requestor"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td class=\"data\"><strong>REMARKS:</strong></td>
    
    -- if condition sample--
    if {
    $rowwaf["remarks"] == proceed
    <td style="color: green">".$rowwaf["remarks"]."</td></tr>
    }
    else {
    $rowwaf["remarks"] == hold
    <td style="color: red">".$rowwaf["remarks"]."</td></tr>
    }
 ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just set a variable for your color(also the code you provided won't work):

```
<?php
if ($rowwaf['remarks'] === 'proceed') {
   $color = 'green';
} elseif ($rowwaf['remarks'] === 'hold') {
   $color = 'red';
}
?>
```

Then use the $color variable in your html

I'd also recommend to use [heredoc syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to create your body and use php variables to do something like :

```
$mailbody = <<<EOF
<td style="color: {$color}">{$rowwaf['remarks']}</td>
EOF;
```

Comment: You could also do something like `$color = 'green'; if ($rowwaf['remarks'] === 'hold') {
   $color = 'red';
}` So you will get rid of the elseif

Comment: But the data should be inside a table. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by _"the data should be inside a table"_. Can you elaborate ?